# ADO.NET Entity Framework software requirements

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net

I have .net 3.5 SP1 and VS 2008 SP1 installed in my machine. But what should I further install to create an Entity framework project. Is there any other add ons that is needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need anything else. BTW there is nothing such as "Entity framework project" in visual studio you can add an "ADO.Net Entity model" to any type of project.

Answer (score 0):

I think hopefully nothing else that I need. I just could add an entity framework as a new item and NOT A new project.